# make fabric error: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory

Tags: go, ubuntu-16.04, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

```
root@qukuai4:~/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric# make peer
build/bin/peer
CGO_CFLAGS=" " GOBIN=/root/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/build/bin go install -tags "" -ldflags "-X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.Version=1.0.0-snapshot-f3c61e6 -X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.BaseVersion=0.3.0 -X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.BaseDockerLabel=org.hyperledger.fabric -X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.DockerNamespace=hyperledger -X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.BaseDockerNamespace=hyperledger" github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
# github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/miekg/pkcs11
vendor/github.com/miekg/pkcs11/pkcs11.go:27:20: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:202: recipe for target 'build/bin/peer' failed
make: *** [build/bin/peer] Error 2
```

error occurs when i built fabric

I have installed libltdl-dev

4.8.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 31 13:57:14 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux